# ValidateAntiForgeryToken return status code 400

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The problem is that if I try and use `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` to my action return status code 400. Why couldn't find my view page?

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id) {
    var model = this.categoryService.GetById(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(CategoriesViewModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        this.categoryService.Update(model);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Category));
    }

    return this.View(model.Id);
}
```

View:

```html
@using CakeStore.App.Areas.Admin.Models.Categories;
@model CategoriesViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";        
}

<h1 class="text-center text-header-page">Edit Category</h1>
<hr class="hr-admin-divider" />
<form class="mx-auto w-50 form-horizontal" method="post" action="Edit">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Id" type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Name" type="text" value="@Model.Name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn button-black-white">Edit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Model:

```
public class CategoriesViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(22,MinimumLength =3,ErrorMessage =AdminConstants.NameRange)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to include the code you linked to. For future questions, please include the code in the question itself (as I've done for you) in order to make it more answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You did not inform the form to contain the token. Try this in your form:

```
<form asp-antiforgery="true" class="mx-auto w-50 form-horizontal" method="post" action="Edit">
```

NOTE: remember you must use the @addTagHelper directive in order to use "asp-antiforgery"